# Commenting / Forum type software for ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We operate a ColdFusion site with a custom CSS acting as a directory of various companies. Depending on the type of company, we have a set of subpages containing specific information pulled from the CMS about the company, such as "location/directions". We're looking to add functionality enabling users to add comments to the existing content. I'm looking for suggestions on open source or other available ColdFusion software out there that could work for this. While we could write something custom, commenting tools have been done a thousand times and probably better than we can do it.

While what we're looking for sounds like a blog or forum, its more of a hybrid. We'd like to be able to add functionality enabling commenting on the content we post in the context we post it in. Seems like there must be something out there that can be easily modified and integrated with our CMS.

Does anyone know of anything out there we should look into?

Comment: From the off-topic flagging menu: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed because it is off-topic for StackOverflow. My recommendation would be to check what your CMS provides. Most of them include some sort of blogging/commenting solution built-in.

Comment: I went looking around for an appropriate place to post these types of questions and of course there is a StackExchange for it - [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (that is currently in Beta). I suppose I will start directing people to post these types of questions over there.

Comment: @Miguel-F Note that [softwarerecs.se] has stricter quality controls than most Stack Exchange sites, and many recommendations questions that get asked on [so] and [su] would not be accepted on SR either. We have [question guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). Please recommend SR only when the guidelines are met, and mention the guidelines whenever you direct people to SR.

Comment: Speaking as an SR mod, I think this question would be ok (but I'm not familiar with Coldfusion or forums). It could perhaps use a more precise description of the minimum requirements (what kind of stuff the comments would be tacked on, whether commenters would need to be authenticated, …), unless that's implied by the context in a way that isn't obvious to a non-proficient reader.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Gilles, I will keep your points in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to vote to close this too, as per the others, but here's an answer anyway.

If you just want to add commenting to existing content, perhaps use [Disqus](http://disqus.com/). It's not locally installable (and is not CFML-based; it's all JS), but it does handle most things one would need if just wanting to add comments to a site.

If you want a native, self-managed solution, unfortunately StackOverflow have deemed that sort of question "unworthy", so you'll need to ask elsewhere. Despite being an entirely reasonable question, for which the answers would be helpful to other people later on (which is - in theory - the raison d'etre of Stack Overflow. Although that's hard to tell, sometimes).

Comment: Agree with your "unworthy" statement. Not all programming questions are black and white. Some are best suited for the other Stack Exchange  sites but this site has the most eyes on it.  It's double edge sword.

Comment: It'd be cool if whoever downvoted this could explain why, then I could improve it.